# How to run a R language(.r) file using Batch file,i need it for jenkins automation

Tags: r

I have **finalR.R**  in R-studio,I want to Run this script in windows cmd as .bat file.please tell how to do that task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In text file write
**"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.3.1\bin\i386\Rscript.exe"  finalR.R**     and save it as xxx.bat file in desktop,save the finalR.R in same location(desktop).now double click the bat file it works.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Rscript?

http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/Rscript.html